# How to get principal user in webapi constructor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

For simplification in an asp.net webapi controller , it is good to use a Principal object (authenticated User Object) as a property or variable that should set in controller constructor. but User is null in constructor. how can i get current user in controller constructor ?

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    string userId;
    public MyController()
    {
        userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        var userName = GetUserNameById(userId);
        return new string[] { userName };
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added some kind of Authentication, being it Basic, OAuth, Windows Integration etc.

Comment: You can't.  at that point in the pipeline the user has not been realized in the request. based what what authentication flow you are using, you can assign the User via an actionfilter

Answer (score 0):

The user is assigned well after the controller has been created. You wont be able to access it in the constructor. Instead you should get the user id directly in your actions after the request and associated user have been assigned to the controller.

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{

    private string GetUserId() {
        return User.Identity.GetUserId();
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        var userName = GetUserNameById(GetUserId());
        return new string[] { userName };
    }
}
```